# Call a function onload, and onscroll also?

Tags: javascript

I have a function which is called when the user scrolls. Works well, but for elements those are on the top of the document (and on the top of the viewport of course), the effects inside the function executes after the first scroll. I need to know if there's a way to do something like this:

```
if(window.onscroll || window.onload){
    function toExecute(){}
}
```

Comment: can't you bind the function for those two events? `window.onscroll = function(){functionToExecute()}` and `window.onload = function(){functionToExecute()}`

Comment: I can, that is the final solution. I was just avoided from that maybe costs too much resources, calling it (the onload function) just for a moment, but it's not. I think that's why it's called just once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to bind the same function to both the `load` and the `scroll` event.
However, since the scroll handler is called very rapidly and can easily cause performance issues on either mobile devices or older browsers, it's better to [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the scroll handler.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('foo called at ' + new Date());
}

let timer;
function debouncedFoo() {
  if (timer) return;
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    timer = null;
    foo();
  }, 20);
}

window.addEventListener('load', foo);
window.addEventListener('scroll', debouncedFoo);
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}
```